IAsyncDisposable: should DisposeAsyncCore call Dispose(false)?
In the DisposeAsync documentation, you have the following:
class ExampleConjunctiveDisposableusing : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);

        Dispose(disposing: false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

Specifically, they call Dispose(false) in DisposeAsync.
As I was missing that, I added it to the actual code.
I then started getting random 0xC0000374 (STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION).
These would occur as the class frees the pointer a second time.
I tried adding numerous if (Disposed) return; guards but that didn't fix.
If I remove it the problem is gone... but something seems to be missing now.
Obviously, I use await using, it's for making an overlapped DeviceIoControl as a Task.
Example:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Whatever.Extensions;

public sealed class NativeMemory : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly int Length;

    private readonly nint Pointer;

    private bool Disposed;

    public NativeMemory(int length)
    {
        Pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Length = length);
    }

    public Span<byte> Span
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                return new Span<byte>((void*)Pointer, Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Dispose(false); // BUG when added
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer);

        await ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    ~NativeMemory()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer);

        if (disposing)
        {
            // NOP
        }

        Disposed = true;
    }
}

Question:
How wrong is my implementation?

Why are you calling Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer); twice?

Don't you try to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer); twice - in DisposeAsyncCore() and then in Dispose when you uncomment the problematic line? I suggest to ever check and set Disposed to true, regardless whether you call Dispose or DisposeAsync

Set the Pointer to IntPtr.Zero after freeing so calling twice is a no-op. You should always do this just in case dispose is called a second time.

Well, I follow the docs which, in case you didn't notice, has a note in purple color that saying about calling Dispose(false) in DisposeAsyncCore. The other thing is, why does doing this works 99.9% of the time but not the 0.01%? Is that because of a race condition of some sort? I'm not doing anything special as far as I can tell...

@Charlieface yes, although one loses read-only aspect of pointer, it's a great approach.

I guess the real question is why use DisposeAsync at all, what is async about any of this?

When problematic line is uncommented, you call Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer) twice:
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    // 1st call of Marshal.FreeHGlobal
    await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // 2nd call of Marshal.FreeHGlobal
    Dispose(false); // BUG when added
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

Assuming that disposal is fast and we actually don't want async version, but interface implementation only,
why don't we call Dispose(true) within DisposeAsync()?
// let's not create any state machine with async + await:
// we free resources synchronously and return completed task 
public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
   // Dispose instance properly 
   Dispose(true);

   // Suppress finalization
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

   // return completed task
   return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}

Please note, that since your class is sealed you don't have to implement full IDisposable pattern (there's no use of Dispose(bool disposing) since the class will never be inherited):
public NativeMemory(int length) {
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(length);

    Pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Length = length);

    // Let GC know, that we allocated some memory
    GC.AddMemoryPressure(Length);
}

public void Dispose() {
    if (Disposed)
        return;

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Pointer); 
    // We release memory allocated, let GC know about it
    GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(Length);  

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    Disposed = true;
}

~NativeMemory() {
    Dispose();
}

public ValueTask DisposeAsync() {
   // Dispose instance properly 
   Dispose();

   // return completed task
   return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}


That'll do, thanks.
